# Remove jobs from at queue on a specified date

Tags: scripting, at

I have a series of pending jobs in the queue,

```
$ atq
8   Mon Oct 29 13:21:00 2018
5   Mon Oct 29 10:36:00 2018
15  Mon Oct 29 13:31:00 2018
4   Mon Oct 29 10:35:00 2018
18  Mon Oct 29 15:55:00 2018
3   Mon Oct 29 10:31:00 2018
16  Mon Oct 29 15:54:00 2018
11  Mon Oct 29 13:24:00 2018
12  Mon Oct 29 13:24:00 2018
17  Mon Oct 29 15:53:00 2018
10  Mon Oct 29 13:23:00 2018
19  Tue Oct 30 15:43:00 2018
2   Mon Oct 29 07:41:00 2018
6   Mon Oct 29 10:41:00 2018
7   Mon Oct 29 13:20:00 2018
9   Mon Oct 29 13:22:00 2018
```

and plan to remove them job on Oct 29. Fortunately, atrm could remove multiple jobs

```
atrm 8 5 15 4
```

despite this, a iteration might be a better solution,

```
$ atq | grep "Oct 29"
18  Mon Oct 29 15:55:00 2018
3   Mon Oct 29 10:31:00 2018
16  Mon Oct 29 15:54:00 2018
11  Mon Oct 29 13:24:00 2018
12  Mon Oct 29 13:24:00 2018
17  Mon Oct 29 15:53:00 2018
10  Mon Oct 29 13:23:00 2018
2   Mon Oct 29 07:41:00 2018
6   Mon Oct 29 10:41:00 2018
7   Mon Oct 29 13:20:00 2018
9   Mon Oct 29 13:22:00 2018
```

How could I select the first field of the job number so as to iterating them?

Comment: Erm, what are you trying to do? Do you want to clean up jobs that should have run, but did not?

Comment: yes, they are on pending queue which should be executed days ago. yesterday will never come again, what's the problem of the pending queue? @SimonRichter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just pipe the `atq` output and process it a bit:

```
atrm $( atq | grep 'Oct 29' | cut -d' ' -f 1 | tr '\n' ' ' )
```

What is being done:

- grep `Oct 29` from `atq` output
- select the first fields only using `cut` and assuming a space as separator
- make newlines to spaces using `tr`

This gives you just the job numbers of `at` on a single line which then can be your input for `atrm`.

Pretest the selection by listing the job IDs only with just using

```
 atq | grep 'Oct 29' | cut -d' ' -f 1 | tr '\n' ' '
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need the `tr '\n' ' '` within the command substitution expression.

Answer (score 5):

```
atq | awk '/Oct 29/ { print $1 }'
```

This would print the job IDs of the jobs that contain the string `Oct 29`.

What the `awk` code is doing is to match the given regular expression against each of the input lines, and for the lines that matches it prints the first whitespace-delimited field on the line (the job ID).

Passing the result of this short pipeline to `xargs atrm` would remove the jobs:

```
atq | awk '/Oct 29/ { print $1 }' | xargs atrm
```

The `xargs` utility reads from its standard input stream and executes the given utility with the argument read.  If there are *many* arguments (probably not in this case), `xargs` may execute the utility multiple times.