# atrm pending tasks using pipeline

Tags: bash, at

I have a few tasks in the pending `at` job queue,

```
$ atq
28  Wed Oct 31 10:23:00 2018
27  Tue Oct 30 21:20:00 2018
25  Tue Oct 30 21:19:00 2018
26  Tue Oct 30 21:20:00 2018
20  Tue Oct 30 18:25:00 2018
30  Wed Oct 31 10:59:00 2018
32  Wed Oct 31 21:03:00 2018
23  Tue Oct 30 18:28:00 2018
31  Wed Oct 31 13:58:00 2018
19  Tue Oct 30 15:43:00 2018
21  Tue Oct 30 18:27:00 2018
```

I'd like to get the job number and remove them

```
$ atq | awk '{print $1}'
20
30
32
23
31
19
21
```

However, it did not work as intended

```
$ atq | awk '{print $1}'| atrm ; atq
20  Tue Oct 30 18:25:00 2018
30  Wed Oct 31 10:59:00 2018
32  Wed Oct 31 21:03:00 2018
23  Tue Oct 30 18:28:00 2018
31  Wed Oct 31 13:58:00 2018
19  Tue Oct 30 15:43:00 2018
21  Tue Oct 30 18:27:00 2018
```

I solved the problem with command substituion

```
$ atrm $(echo "$(atq | awk '{print $1}')")
```

Why pipeline not perform as expected to `atrm`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very similar to your question "[Remove jobs from at queue on a specified date](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478605)", with the difference that you now want to delete all jobs.

To remove *all* pending `at` jobs from the queue, use

```
atrm -a
```

On systems where `-a` is not a valid option to `atrm`, use

```
atq | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs atrm
```

The tiny `awk` script in the middle of the pipeline will print the first column (the `at` job IDs) from the output of `atq`, and `xargs` will run `atrm` with these as arguments.

This is almost identical to [my answer to your other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/478607/116858) apart from the fact that the `print $1` is executed unconditionally.

---

The reason why

```
atq | awk '{ print $1 }' | atrm
```

does not work is that `atrm` is not reading the job IDs from its standard input.  It expects the IDs on its command line.

Your "fix" is to use two nested command substitutions:

```
atrm $( echo "$( atq | awk '{ print $1 }' )" )
```

This could be cut down to use only single command substitution (as `echo $(...)` is, in this case, the same as running the command within the substitution, without the `echo`),

```
atrm $( atq | awk '{ print $1 }' )
```

Comment: oh, I get it. it seems a subtle difference bewteen get an on the fly input like `sort` and  command line argument like atq.